# HTML Table with no edges

Tags: html, css, html-table

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000; width: calc(100% + 40px); margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 3</p>     
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 3</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
```

I am trying to get the table right to the edge, left and right, so that vertical scrolling is not possible. Just putting width to calc(100% + 20px) won't work. Still then scrolling vertical is possible, though minimal. 
Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! you are essentially adding 40px to the 100% width space, making it scroll 40px past the max width, just remove the +40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers are right. If you change width of the table to be `width: 100%`, the table won't extend past the browser window.

Viewing your code and your comment about the not wanting to display the "edge" to the right of the table, I assume you're original goal is to fit the table to the browser width? To accomplish this, I'd look into zero-ing out the `margin` of the `<body>` to get rid of it's default margin. You can see how this is accomplished here: https://jsfiddle.net/urL2nwem/

Here is also an article from CSS Tricks addressing unintended body overflow that may help you prevent this issue in the future: https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer if that's what you were going for. Happy coding!

Comment: I'm waiting for flagging it due to the reason that if I zero out the margin of the body the following content losses its margin, too. Have to try whether if it works or not regarding the following content.

Comment: That then goes into a discussion of how you structure your html into separate containers. If you want to have some content extend the full browser width but have other content have margin, you can apply a style to a later <div> or <section> element that gives you the spacing you need: https://jsfiddle.net/tLf08dkr/

Comment: Yes,  that's what I want to do but there it get's tricky, too. The main table should extend the full browser width whereas the inner table(s) should contain its standard margin. Just putting the table into a div and set the margin to 0px won't work.

Comment: You'll need to target the elements within <tr> to have margin. Even without zero-ing out the body, depending on what elements you use within a table cell, they won't have any margin applied. So in your case, you need to target the <p> tags specifically and give them a margin value.

If you don't mind me asking, what's your current experience with html and css?

Comment: Just to quickly respond to your question about my current experience: I've recently taught it myself, so I am a rookie I can't deny it.

Comment: I've read the article you've linked and looked for some other possible solutions. This, however, gets to the heart of what I want to have https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/ , though everything applied to a table or its inner tags does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the + 40px it's ok

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000; width: calc(100%); margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 3</p>     
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 3</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
```

Comment: But then I have an edge to the right of the table. That's what I would like to avoid. But somehow it worked by setting the 40px to 18px.

Comment: Okay, maybe you can remove it by removing padding in CSS. Because i'ts not right to put more than 100% because all of computers don't have the same size

Comment: Yes, you're right. This might be the better way to do it to accomplish the same display over all devices. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This way it works somehow.

```html
<body>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #000; width: calc(100% + 18px); margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 3</p>     
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p style="color: white">Test 3</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```